# Get data using Code First and foreign key

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, ado.net

I thought this will be something straight-forward but it's been a whole day and I still cant' find an answer. Let's get a very simple example. We have a class `Post`:

```
   public class Post
{
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

And also `Blog` class:

```
    public class Blog
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I'm using the `Blog` data (particularly in dataGridView) I can access the value of every property just by setting the name of the property in the dataGridView. The only data that cannot be accessed directly is the data that I get through my foreign key from post.

How can I get `Post.Content` for every row in my DB? Because now I can only set `Post` in my dataGridView, which returns something like `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxy...` .

Comment: 1) Which UI Framework are you using (i.e. Web Forms, MVC, etc.)? 2) Shouldn't Blog have a collection of Posts?

Comment: I'm using `Windows Forms` - `MDI` specificly. As for the code I use the example here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx

Comment: You've copied the code wrong.

Comment: Oh man...you're right :( Now it's fine, could you help me anyways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a DTO type like this

```
public class PostDto
{
    public string Blog { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

populate it by

```
var dtos = from b in db.Blogs
           from p in b.Posts
           select new PostDto {
                                 Blog = b.Name,
                                 Content = p.Content
                              };
```

and bind `dtos.ToList()` to the DGV. THe DGV does not support expandable rows, so you can only display a flat structure. If you don't want the repetitive blog names you may consider a master-detail layout with two grids.